# What does the App Engine "internal traffic" means?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firewall, google-vpc

I would like to configure my microservices to only accept internal traffic.
By "internal traffic", I mean other App Engine services, running in the same Project.

Is this possible?
What is meant by internal traffic?

When I set the ingress to internal traffic only, my services are not accessible from other app engine services.

PS. I use a `vpc_access_connector` for connecting from a compute engine

Comment: The answer is generally useful and well articulated, but does not answer the question (at least I do not understand if it does). Typically, internal traffic is defined by private IPs. As an app engine only has a public IP, I am not sure how 2 app engine services can communicate privately.

Comment: @IoannisDeligiannis does this answer your question on the error when setting ingress to internal traffic only? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67572327/16531441

Comment: @Mabel It does indeed. Feel free to mark as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

'Internal traffic' in GCP is just similar to the general idea of internal traffic when creating firewall rules in any platform. However, there are other set of [firewall rules that are implemented in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#firewall_rules_in) that can affect incoming (ingress) or outgoing (egress) connections that you should also consider aside from the firewall rules you created. The following rules are:

- Google Cloud doesn't allow certain IP protocols, such as egress traffic on TCP port 25 within a VPC network. For more information, see [always blocked traffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic).
- Google Cloud always allows communication between a VM instance and its corresponding metadata server at 169.254.169.254. For more information, see [always allowed traffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#alwaysallowed).
- Every network has two [implied firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules) that permit outgoing connections and block incoming connections. Firewall rules that you create can override these implied rules.
- The default network is [pre-populated with firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc) that you can delete or modify.

Since you are using a VPC, you need to consider the 'always blocked traffic' firewall rules that are being applied in your project which is stated in the first bullet. If you are using protocols other than TCP, UDP, ICMP, IPIP, AH, ESP, SCTP, and GRE to external IP addresses of Google Cloud resources, then this is the reason why your services are not accessible.

Additionally, you may check this [article](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#error_messages_when_creating_or_updating_a_firewall_rule) on the common issues encountered when creating VPC firewall rules.